# Distribution of parameter under the null hypothesis for mixture distributions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

I am conducting a classical hypothesis test concerning the value of some parameter, i.e. $H_{0}:\theta=\theta_{0}$. I'll denote the  distribution of $\theta$ under the null as $f(\theta)$.

Suppose there is a 50% chance that $f(\theta)=g(\theta)$, a 30% chance $f(\theta)=h(\theta)$ and a 20% chance that $f(\theta)=m(\theta)$; where $g$, $h$ and $m$ are all known.

Intuitively, it doesn't seem to follow that one can use $0.5g(\theta)+0.3h(\theta)+0.2m(\theta)$ to form the distribution of $\theta$ under $H_{0}$ (the resulting distribution doesn't have a practical interpretation and of course won't consistently estimate the true distribution). Does anyone have any suggestions of what I could do? Is there even a solution to this problem?

PS Not sure if relevant; but g, h and m were formed using a kernel nonparametric density estimator.

Edit:

- The alternative hypothesis is $H_{A}:\theta≠\theta_{0}$.
- $\theta$ is neither a scale nor location parameter. It is actually one of the coefficients (the intercept) in a LS-regression model, but I am applying an algorithm to get around a tricky (and rather unique) multiple comparisons problem. The final step in this is forming the null distribution to conduct a hypothesis test, and whilst I have calculated the vector of probabilities (0.5, 0.3, 0.2) and the corresponding null-distributions (g, h, m), I have became stuck with this final step!

Comment: Tantalizing question, but some gaps:  Is $H_a: \theta \ne \theta_0$?  Do you know how you would estimate $\theta$?  Do you know whether $\theta$ is a location or scale parameter?

Comment: Apologies for overlooking this. I have edited the question.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying info. I think your linear combination of three PDFs is the PDF of the mixture distribution. See simulation below. Also, please see Wikipedia on 'mixture distribution'.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment:**  I want to use simulation to demonstrate
the PDF of your mixture of distributions. Let the
first be $Exp(rate = 1)$ (50%), the second be $Norm(\mu=2,\sigma=1/2)$ (30%), and the third be $Unif(2,4)$ (20%).

**Simulation.** The program below
makes these choices for 100,000 observations, plots the histogram,
and then plots the weighted average of the PDFs that you do not find
intuitive--and I do.

```
 B = 10^5;  x = k = numeric(m)
 for (i in 1:m) {
   h = sample(1:3, 1, prob=c(.5,.3,.2));  k[i] = h
   x[i] = (h==1)*rexp(1,1) + (h==2)*rnorm(1,2,.5) + (h==3)*runif(1,2,4) }

 table(k)/B
 ## k
 ##       1       2       3 
 ## 5.00413 2.99687 1.99900 

 mean(x);  sd(x)
 ## 1.699684   # apprx E(X)
 ## 1.118747   # apprx SD(X)
```

**Comments on simulation results.** It seems from `table(k)/B` that the distributions were chosen
in the intended proportions. Also, $E(X) = .5(1) + .3(2) + .2(3) = 1.7$ is well approximated. So the simulation program is working
as intended.

It is a little more difficult to find the variance $V(X)$ of the mixture distribution
because it reflects both the variances of the three individual
distributions and the scatter of their means. (See the Wikipedia article on 'mixture distributions' under moments.)

```
 hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2", ylim=c(0,.5))
 curve(.5*dexp(x,1)+.3*dnorm(x,2,.5)+.2*dunif(x,2,4), 
    lwd=2, col="blue", n=1001, add=T)
```

[image]

It seems that the weighted sum of PDFs is the correct PDF. I deliberately chose
three different distributional shapes in order to get a
combined distribution with an unusually shaped PDF and a relatively obvious
visual test of fit. (The bit of a tail to the right of 4 is
mainly due to the exponential component, partly to normal.)

**Next?** We will have to think about how to do the testing. Maybe something
like a one-sample t statistic will work, and we can discover
the critical value of its distribution through simulation. Because
you have seen some data, you may have better suggestions what to try next.